# How to targeting Specific Elements with Common Classes, using jQuery Toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm creating a drop down menu that will be reused many times on a single page.

The following code works great when there's only one drop down menu. But when there are multiple drop downs, clicking a single `.dropdown` will result in all the `.dd_menu`'s on the page being revealed.

### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.dropdown').click(function(){
      $('.dd_menu').toggle();
   });
});
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="mini_button" href="#">Actions</a>

    <div class="dd_menu">
        <a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
        <a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
        <a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Is there some what to target only the `.dd_menu` that is inside the particular `.downdown` which was clicked?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find an element by class name, from a known parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034699/find-an-element-by-class-name-from-a-known-parent-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit the selector to the `.dd_menu` that is a child of the current clicked `.dropdown` div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.dropdown').click(function(){
      $('.dd_menu', this).toggle(); // <========== used this as a context.
   });
});
```

`jQuery( selector [, context] )`:

- `selector` A string containing a selector expression
- `context` A **DOM Element**, Document, or jQuery to use as context

[**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

You can also use the `find` function: `$(this).find('.dd_menu')` but it exactly the same. the context selector is calling the `find` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$(this).children('.dd_menu').toggle();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.dropdown').on('click', 'a', function(){
       $('.dd_menu:eq('+$(this).parent().index()+')').toggle();
   });
});​
```

Comment: Why are you using delegate event? and the inner selector is so verbose.