# How to get to specific element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML structureL

```
<div class="services-article-elements-single">
    <div class="services-article-description">
        <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">read more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="services-article-after-roll"></div>
</div>
```

I want after clicking a button something happen with my `<div class="services-article-after-roll"></div>`

So far, I have:

```
jQuery('.services-article-read-more-btn').click(() =>{
   // ????????
})
```

I think the appropriate method is `find()` but I'm not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an element by class name, from a known parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034699/find-an-element-by-class-name-from-a-known-parent-element)

Answer (score 1):

Just select your element. In this case, you can [select you element by class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). In my simple example, the button shows or hides a div.

```js
$('.services-article-read-more-btn').click(function() {
   $(".services-article-after-roll").toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services-article-elements-single">
    <div class="services-article-description">
        <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">My button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="services-article-after-roll">MY DIV</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** if you have a structure with more than one div with class `services-article-elements-single`, you can select a wrapper div using [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then find the element **inside** that container using [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function.

```js
$('.services-article-read-more-btn').click(function() {
   var elementWrapper = $(this).closest(".services-article-elements-single");
   elementWrapper.find(".services-article-after-roll").toggle();
})
```

```css
.services-article-elements-single {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="services-article-elements-single">
    <div class="services-article-description">
        <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">My button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="services-article-after-roll">MY DIV</div>
</div>

<div class="services-article-elements-single">
    <div class="services-article-description">
        <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">My button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="services-article-after-roll">MY DIV</div>
</div>

<div class="services-article-elements-single">
    <div class="services-article-description">
        <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">My button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="services-article-after-roll">MY DIV</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not the case because i have a few such elements and when i click one of them it all this elements dothe stuff. I want ony clicked element do the stuff

Comment: I have edited my answer to toggle only the div which is inside the same container as the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery itself is a function which allows selecting elements. You can just use `jQuery('.services-article-after-roll')` and you will get the element.

```
jQuery('.services-article-read-more-btn').click(() => {
  const $servicesArticleAfterRoll = jQuery('.services-article-after-roll');
  // ... do stuff
})
```

Comment: not the case because i have a few such elements and when i click one of them it all this elements dothe stuff. I want ony clicked element do the stuff

Comment: The follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49896973/2547435, using the closest method is the best option

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than one 'roll', you'll need to use a context specific selector - that just means use `this` within the event handler:

```js
$(".services-article-read-more-btn").click(function() {

    $(this).closest(".services-article-elements-single")
           .find(".services-article-after-roll")
           .fadeIn();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services-article-elements-single">
    <div class="services-article-description">
        <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">read more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="services-article-after-roll" style='display:none;'>more info</div>
</div>
<div class="services-article-elements-single">
    <div class="services-article-description">
        <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">read more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="services-article-after-roll" style='display:none;'>more info</div>
</div>
```

Where `.closest` finds the closest parent with that class (the containing div) and then `.find` goes back down within that div to find the related details.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you require you can use DOM traversal. In the click handler you can use `closest()` to get the nearest common parent element to the one which raised the event and the one you want to target. Then you can use `find()` to get that element before amending it as required. In the example below I just toggle a class to hide/show them:

```js
$('.services-article-read-more-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.services-article-elements-single').find('.services-article-after-roll').toggleClass('show');
})
```

```css
.services-article-after-roll {
  display: none;
}

.services-article-after-roll.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services-article-elements-single">
  <div class="services-article-description">
    <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">read more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="services-article-after-roll">After roll...</div>
</div>
<div class="services-article-elements-single">
  <div class="services-article-description">
    <button class="services-article-read-more-btn">read more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="services-article-after-roll">After roll...</div>
</div>
```